# error overloading operator '>>'

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, istream

I am trying to overload the >> operator, check my code, it's the most reduced program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class MyClass{
private:
   string bar;
   int foo;

public:
   MyClass(){
   bar="";
   foo=0;
};

istream& operator>>(istream& is){
    is >> bar >> foo;
    return is;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os){
    os << bar << foo;
    return os;
};

~MyClass(){};
};

int main()
{
    MyClass* a = new MyClass();

    cin >> *a;

    delete a;

    return 0;
}
```

This code **doesn't compile**, I've googled before post my question and I found the trouble could be the most vexing parse, but i cannot imagine how to fix it.

Anyway, I don't know where is the problem, when i try to compile, the compiler throws:

First:

```
error: no match for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ and ‘MyClass’)
cin >> *a;
~~~~^~~~~
```

Then, after trying to convert the types to int, double, char, etc it throws:

```
/usr/include/c++/6.1.1/istream:924:5: nota: candidate: 
std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, _Tp&) [con _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = MyClass] <coincidencia cercana>
 operator>>(basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __is, _Tp& __x)
 ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/6.1.1/istream:924:5: nota:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
error: no se puede unir el l-valor ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ a ‘std::basic_istream<char>&&’
cin >> *a;
```

**What can I do to solve this issue?**

Comment: Someone needs a friend :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overloading the input and output operators can't be done as member functions. The reason is that when you defined the `>>` or `<<` operators as member functions the object instance of the class must be on the *left* hand side of the operator.

Instead define the operator functions as non-member friend functions (which can be done inline in the class) like

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    ...

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyClass const& object)
    {
        return os << object.bar << object.foo;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

">>" and "<<" operators are usually not implemented as member functions because the first argument is an implicit object of that class in a member function but you can do that and it will work if you would do something like *a >> cin in your main.Other wise implement these operators as global functions as explained in the above answer.